# Remove white space only between 2 strings

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a string like this: `l' opp lop` and I need to remove the white space between `l'` and `o`, so it has to return `l'opp lop`.

But I also need to handle strings with different cases like: `L' opp LOP`, `L' Opp lop`, `l' Opp lop` and return the correct string without the extra space between the those string, so the result has to be: `L'opp LOP`, `L'Opp lop`, `l'Opp lop`.

I have tried `$new = str_ireplace( "l' o", "l'o", $string );` but it always returns a string that includes `l'o` so if the string is `L'Opp lop` the result is always in lower case: `l'opp lop`.

Is it possible to have a solution using regex because I also will need to use it to match `l' a`, `l' i`, `l' u`, `l' e`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
~\b(l)'\s+([a-z])~i
```

And replace with `$1$2`.

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vC8hR3/1)

The point is to use *capturing groups* with the subpatterns that you need to get back after replacement.

**Regex explanation:**

- `\b` - starting word boundary
- `(l)`- match and capture into Group 1 a letter `l` or `L` (as `/i` case insensitive modifier is used)
- `'` - a literal apostrophe
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces (you may use `\h+` to limit to horizontal spaces only)
- `([a-z])` - match and capture into Group 2 any ASCII letter (lower- and uppercase).

In the replacement pattern, Group 1 and 2 are backreferences with `$1` and `$2` respectively.